# How to add event listener/ionChange on month change event in an ion-datetime object?

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, ionic-framework, calendar

When the user changes the month i need to re-render the highlightedDates: a query is called and retrieve all the dates of that month.
It works if the user use the top button to manually select a month and the year, but if he just click on the arrows: "<" ">" then the ionChange is not trigger.

```
  <div class="calendar">
    <ion-datetime
      [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"
      presentation="date"
      locale="it-IT"
      [highlightedDates]="allAppointments"
      (ionChange)="createAppointmentList()"
    >
    </ion-datetime>
```

Basically i need an eventListener when the user click on the arrows of the calendar

Comment: You can find a workaround at https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/25730#issuecomment-1213238159 it might need a bit of tweaking, but it's a workable solution and will get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat found a solution thanks to Misha Mashina comment

```
  initMonthObserver(){
    const monthText = document.querySelector('ion-datetime')?.shadowRoot?.querySelector('.calendar-header')?.querySelector('ion-label');
    const elementToObserve = document.querySelector('ion-datetime')?.shadowRoot?.querySelector('.calendar-body')

    if (elementToObserve) { 
      const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {

        this.monthString = monthText?.textContent;
        let parts = this.monthString.split(" ")
        let monthIndex = this.monthNames.indexOf(parts[0].toLowerCase())
        let monthNumber = monthIndex + 1
        let year = parts[1]

        if(this.monthString){
          this.monthToDate = new Date(year, monthNumber).toISOString()
          this.queryAppsPerMonth(this.monthToDate)
        }

      })
      const observerConfig = {
        childList: true, 
        subtree: true, 
      };
      observer.observe(elementToObserve, observerConfig)
    }
  }
```

Got the calendar element using:

```
 document.querySelector('ion-datetime')?.shadowRoot?.querySelector('.calendar-body')
```

Then MutationObserver to track mutation of that